Understanding Marklogic's geo.regionDe9im result
I received 2FFF1FFFF DE-9IM result for the following query:
var marklogicGeo = require('/MarkLogic/geospatial/geospatial');
relation = marklogicGeo.regionDe9im(
  "POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))", 
  "POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))");

As two polygons are exactly the same I was expecting a result that could be interpreted as TFFFTFFFT (e.g. 2FFF1FFF2), which is a DE-9IM Intersection Pattern for equivalence (by GeoSPARQL function definitions of geof:sfEquals, geof:ehEquals, and geof:rcc8eq)
It is unclear to me why would the last intersection, the intersection of exteriors, be False?
Is this a bug in MarkLogic or am I missing something?

There seem to be discrepancies between the GeoSPARQL specification and the DE-9IM papers describing the EQUALS predicate.
https://docs.ogc.org/is/22-047r1/22-047r1.html
vs.
https://giswiki.hsr.ch/images/3/3d/9dem_springer.pdf
OGC GeoSPARQL spec seems to be more strict on the equals relation.
TFFFTFFFT vs. T*F**FFF* .
MarkLogic GeoSPARQL features extend the second link's DE-9IM specification, as the original geospatial features were built before the GeoSPARQL features.
If you run the following in MarkLogic, it evaluates to true.
const marklogicGeo = require('/MarkLogic/geospatial/geospatial');
relation = marklogicGeo.equals(
  "POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))", 
  "POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))");

In SPARQL:
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>

select *

{
BIND(geof:sfEquals("POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))",
                   "POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))") as ?equals)
}

returns "true"^^xs:boolean
Hope this helps.

Your assertion is correct. GeoSPARQL and MarkLogic do have different definition of Equals relation.
My question was focused on the fact that MarkLogic evaluates 2FFF1FFFF DE-9IM pattern as relation between two for exactly the same shapes, instead of 2FFF1FFF2.

You are correct, with a second look, the papers state that Exterior/Exterior is trivially true for all relations. So, MarkLogic should return 2FFF1FFF2.
